# Calculating coordinates given a reference point and distance

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I am using QGIS 3.6 and trying to calculate coordinates (lat&long) from a point given the distance. I have the lat&long for reference point and have the distance from the reference point.

[image: Table 1]

Points A, B, and C are reference locations of a road

[image: Table 2]

X, Y, and Z are building within a distance from A toward point B
How can I get the lat and long for X, Y, Z?

Comment: Don't you need a direction as well?

Comment: Can I get the direction from point A to B? Cause these buildings are on A to B line

Comment: Oh, so the buildings are *on the line* that starts at A, goes to B, then C?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the points A, B and C to create a line. There are many ways to do this, including:

   - use the `points to path` tool, or
   - use the `geometry by expression` tool, or
   - create a line with three vertices, and edit the vertex coordinates using the `vertex editor`
2. Use the `interpolate point on line` tool to create a point at each specified distance. To create multiple points, there are two options. Choose the one that seems most convenient for your dataset.

   - Method one: Run the tool once for each point. This method creates a separate layer for each point. You can merge them into a single layer using the `merge vector layers` tool.
   - Method two: Make a duplicate line for every point you want to create (select the line, copy and paste). Add an attribute field called distance. Enter the point distances in this field.

     [image]

   Use the distance field for the distance value.

   [image]
3. Get the lat/long of those points by

   - clicking on each point with the Identify tool, or
   - use the add geometry attributes tool to add lat/long to the attribute table

Comment: You can also use `interpolate point on line` for step 2

Comment: @strythe, thank you for the suggestion. I thought there was a tool that did the same as `points along geometry` but allowed a data-defined override for the distance value.

Comment: I was hoping there'd be a tool for this too, one which takes a field of distances and a line geometry.I had to write a script to interpolate multiple points without having to duplicate the line.